# How is eSIM attached to carrier?

Tags: sim

I am developing IoT device which has integrated SIM7080G. I would like to know if I rather should go with basic SIM or use new eSIM ICs like ST4SI2M0020TPIFW.

What's wondering me is when I buy eSIM IC and then solder it on PCB then how I am going to be registered to e.g. Vodafone / AT&T.

What's the process? Is eSIM IC carrying some sort of ID that I will tell to carrier or I have to flash IC via something to carry some profile?

How is this done?

Comment: eSIMs are provisioned, maybe that can help you find the relevant gsma documents